# Show tha triadiagonal is M-matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

How to show that a tridiagonal matrix $A=(-1,2,-1)$ is an M-matrix, meaning that the entries of its inverse are nonnegative?

Answer (score 1):

It is well known that the eigenvalues of (the symmetric) $A$ are [positive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix#Eigenvalues) so $A$ is SPD.

A symmetric Z-matrix is an M-matrix iff $A$ is SPD. See the third condition listed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-matrix).